# How to stop cold drafts caused by a warped door sill?

Tags: doors, draft

One of my external door sill weather-strip is slightly warped near the center producing an area where cold air can flow in.

[image: Door sill weatherstrip.]

The door sweep appears to make good contact on the left and right sides of the door so air flows through in the middle.

What is the optimal way to repair this type of draft? (both economically and from a heat retention standpoint)

Should I use an adhesive type door weather-strip ([http://www.amazon.com/Duck-1302370-Self-Adhesive-Insulating-1-75-Inch/dp/B002GKC2TY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420496967&sr=8-1&keywords=adhesive+draft+stopper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GKC2TY))

or should I find a way to replace the door sill weather-strip? What would the work entail to access and replace the sill weather-strip?

Comment: Using a door sweep (which attaches to the door itself) certainly would not hurt, but if the sill/threshold is actually warped, @bobfandango's answer also definitely applies. Personally I would probably go towards a metal door sweep that screws on rather than the adhesive/plastic one you linked, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from the picture but it seems likely that the floor beneath the middle of the sill is sagging or just lower than the ends of the sill for whatever reason.  If that is the case, and it were me, I'd pull up the existing sill and shim up the area that is too low.  Set a straight edge across the width of the door frame to see how much material needs to be added under the sill.  I would use roofing felt for that.  You can cut it with a utility knife, and it won't rot or compress very easily. Once you have filled in the low area so that no light shows beneath the straight edge, re-install the sill.  Another advantage of using roofing felt is that the screws you use to secure the sill will drive through the felt quite easily.

Here is a link to a website that discusses how to use shingles and felt to level an entire subfloor prior to flooring installation.  http://bit.ly/1Ii80Qi  The scope of that project is much larger that what you are dealing with, but the principles involved are exactly the same.